# Can IUPnPDeviceFinder find other devices not in upnp namespace?

Tags: windows-8.1, upnp

I'm trying to find a UPnP device in the urn:dslforum.org namespace with this code:

```
   com_ptr<IUPnPDeviceFinder> upnp_device_finder;
   CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UPnPDeviceFinder, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
       IID_IUPnPDeviceFinder, (LPVOID*)&upnp_device_finder);
   if (upnp_device_finder.empty()) return;

   com_ptr<IUPnPDevices> upnp_devices;
   upnp_device_finder->FindByType(L"urn:dslforum-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1",
      0, &upnp_devices);
   if (upnp_devices.empty()) return;

   long num_devices = 0;
   upnp_devices->get_Count(&num_devices);
   assert(num_devices != 0);
```

With Wireshark I see my device responding, but `num_devices` is always 0. I also have another `InternetGatewayDevice` in that LAN which is found via:

```
FindByType(L"urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1", 0, &upnp_devices);
```

So the only difference I can see is the namespace. Seems the Windows 8.1 IUPnPDeviceFinder can only find the devices in the `urn:schemas-upnp-org` space? Am I missing something? Any Ideas?

Comment: What device xml does your target device report?  Does this xml report that the device type matches your search string?

Comment: yes, the XML reports exactly this deviceType: urn:dslforum-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1. I also tried to find it by it's UDN, not found. Allthough I see the responses in Wireshark